# Convert a byte array to a string array

Tags: go

In the following method, I attempted to redefine the string method on the IPAddr type by appending bytes to an array of string

```
type IPAddr [4]byte

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    var s []string
    for _, i := range ip {
        s = append(s, i)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(strings.Join(s, "."))
}
```

> cannot use i (type byte) as type string in append

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MbSac2RvLQ3)

Comment: The error is pretty clear, IMHO. What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: @Biffen, I do understand the error. However, I wonder how to convert the byte to a string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since your type is an array with a small length, so I would recommend just building the string without ranging over the elements:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nOSj-EyXuyf

If you want to implement your solution by joining the string slice, you need to convert the bytes to their decimal representation using the `strconv` package:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := make([]string, 0, len(ip))
    for _, i := range ip {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(int(i)))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}
```

Comment: Yes, it could be an option. But I do wonder, how one will go about converting byte array to a string array